# Projections (linear maps ) and inner product spaces problem

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

V is a finite dimensional vector space. I am given a linear map $E:V\rightarrow V$ which is a projection so that $E^2=E$. I am also given that $V=Im E\oplus KerE$ (which follows from it being a projection anyway). 
$E^*$ is the adjoint linear map.I have shown if $E=E^*$ then $(ImE)^\perp=KerE$.
I need to show the reverse direction.But I am stuck.
I have got as far as showing that $KerE=Ker(E^*)$ so the restrictions of $E $and $E^*$ restricted to the Kernels are equal. It then follows that$ ImE=Im(E^*)$ You can get the orthogonal complements of the images are equal and because we are working in a finite dimensional vector space $V$ we can apply the fact that the orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement of the subspace gives back the original subspace and so $ImE=Im(E^*)$. I spent a bit of time trying to show the stronger result that the images were equal AND the stuff in both sets was mapped from the same stuff by $E$ and $E^*$ showing $E$ and $E^*$ were the same but I couldn't do this.

By adjoint $E^*$ I mean the map such that $\langle Ev,w \rangle= \langle v,E^*w \rangle \forall v,w \in V$ I forgot to add V is an inner product space, sorry.

Comment: @amd its been edited

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/q/584379/265466 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28linear_algebra%29.